# How Can I measure view Time on a Div?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for to calculate how much time a visitor read my post using JavaScript. Like I have

3 div.
each div contains information when visitor read any div I will calculate the time. it will not work when somebody scroll down not staying on the div. User must stay on the div. Each particular div will generate its own reading time. Actually I did not implement any code. Looking for a better solution. Thank you

Comment: GA and GTM are intended for this kind of tracking. You may want to look at it.

Comment: thank you keysl. But how can I grab this info from GA ?

Comment: If you want to implement it yourself, the best guess for the reading time is probably to calculate how long each div is in the viewport. [This](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-test-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-with-vanilla-javascript/) is a Block post explaining how to do it. You just want to start a timer when the element enters the viewport and stop the timer if it leaves the viewport.

Comment: Yeah so its relatively easy process one was adding the right dimensions, events etc in the code itself. you can add that to the div for example. Then next is once you setup this you can just hop in on the dashboard to check the performance, retains, sessions etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some web analytics services like `google analytics` or `hotjar` that provide a good services.

If you want to do something custom that match exactly you use case

I'd suggest using `IntersectionObserver` API

```js
const onIntersection = (entries) => {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      console.log(entry);
    }
  }
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(onIntersection);
observer.observe(document.querySelector('#div1'));
```

This will tell you when the viewport is on the selected element `#div1` in this case (When the user is seeing the div).
So you can run a timer and check how long the user has been viewing the element.

Useful links:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API/Timing_element_visibility
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API